# Django Rest Framework, passing parameters with GET request, classed based views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like a user to send a GET request to my Django REST API:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/model/?radius=5&longitude=50&latitude=55.1214
```

with his longitude/latitude and radius, passed in parameters, and get the queryset using GeoDjango.

For example, currently I have:

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
```

And what I ideally want is:

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     radius = request.data['radius']
     location = Point(request.data['longitude'],request.data['latitude']
     # filter results by distance using geodjango
     queryset = Model.objects.filer(location__distance_lte=(location, D(m=distance))).distance(location).order_by('distance')
```

Now a couple of immediate errors:

1) `request` is not defined - should I use api_view, i.e. the function based view for this?

2) [DRF page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/) says that request.data is for POST, PUT and PATCH methods only. How can send parameters with GET?

Comment: The modelviewset has a few methods where you can access the REQUEST parameter. Like def get_queryset(self) - self.request, which is probably where you should put your code. Try this and let me know

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can override `get_queryset` method for that purpose. As for query string parameters, you are right, `request.data` holds POST data, you can get query string params through `request.query_params`

```
def get_queryset(self):
    longitude = self.request.query_params.get('longitude')
    latitude= self.request.query_params.get('latitude')
    radius = self.request.query_params.get('radius')

    location = Point(longitude, latitude)

    queryset = Model.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(location, D(m=distance))).distance(location).order_by('distance')

    return queryset
```

Comment: This worked but I had to add `router.register(r'model_name', views.ModelViewSet , base_name='model_name')` in urls.py. However, now POST request gives me the following error: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "model-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

Comment: what if i pass a boolean param?
`self.request.query_params.get` returns a string. Is there a clean way to get boolean params? or should i do a string comparison?

Comment: @saran3h I do not think that there is a way to directly get a boolean value from query_params, you problably should do string comparison in that case.

Comment: request.data does not hold POST data exclusively. If you make a GET request with x-www-urlencoded and use body , request.GET and request.query_params are empty and the data is held in request.data

Comment: This is my url `path('consignmentdocs/<uuid:pk>/', ConsignmentDocsListViewSet.as_view(), name='consignment-docs'),` how do I get the pk using query_params to use in filtering a Model?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, to solve it you can get parameters from url with `self.request.parser_context.get('kwargs')` under the `get_queryset` method.

Answer (score 4):

use this simplest way you can get query param values:

```
request.GET.get("radius")
```

Answer (score 0):

this actually worked for me .
using the `self.request.query_params.get("lead_contact_id")`

```
def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
    # the lead id
    lead_contact_id = self.request.query_params.get("lead_contact_id")
    #  this filter base on the lead id  provided
    feedback = Feedback.objects.filter(object_id=lead_contact_id)
    return feedback
```