# How to handle get request parameter with "/" in djago rest framework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest API framework. I am working on GET API which pull data from database. I am passing parameters in URL like below. This API fails if "item_name" have any "/" in it.

```
API URL:http://localhost:8000/api/getstat/**item_name**
Working: http://localhost:8000/api/getstat/**completed**
Fails for: http://localhost:8000/api/getstat/**NotComplete/failed**

Error: The current path, /api/getstat/**NotComplete/failed**, didn't match any of these.
```

**Any info/help around how to handle this would be really useful or how to escape? so it will not be considered as path**

Comment: Have you tried passing any parameters as querystrings instead of a discrete URL path?  
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299466/django-rest-framework-passing-parameters-with-get-request-classed-based-views) shows how you may be able to do that.

Comment: Can you show the Python code for the /api/getstat/ view?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your time. Currently view looks like below.                              class TrxList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SerializerClass
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        Trx=self.kwargs['item_name']
        querySet=Data.objects.filter('items'=Trx)
        return querySet

Comment: yes, tried with query string instead of discrete URL path and it worked. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

As Matt suggested in comment, tried with query parameter instead of parameters in passing through path and it worked for me. Django support below both approach but one failed for case mentioned like above.

```
Failed: http://localhost:8000/api/getstat/**NotComplete/failed**
worked: http://localhost:8000/api/getstat/?**item=NotComplete/failed**

Read param like "reportID = self.request.query_params.get('item')" in view.
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slashes as %2F.

This is the standard URL encoding for /.

Comment: tried passing '%2F' instead of '/' but didn't worked. Thanks for your input.