# How to pass URL parameters and get the values with GET request method in Django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I want to pass url parameters in this format http://localhost:8000/api/projects/?id=2021&a=2&b=3&c=4 and get the values in view function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing URL parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299466/django-rest-framework-passing-parameters-with-get-request-classed-based-views

Answer (score 0):

In DRF you can get values of perms like this...

```
URL = http://localhost:8000/api/projects/?id=2021&a=2&b=3&c=4

 id = request.query_params.get('id')
 a = request.query_params.get('a')
 b = request.query_params.get('b')
 c = request.query_params.get('c')

 print(id,a,b,c)
```

#### Postman Screen

[image]